# Android Studio - UIThread, how to stop overloading?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have simple GUI that let's me input some text, has 2 switches and one "continue" button.
For some reason, it seems too much for my device to work with and I need to wait for a long time before I can click continue, otherwise app will crash.

Also, you know that "blinking line" when you are typing something and then stop so program waits for you to continue ? If I click "continue" when that line is visible, app will crash.

It seems that is too much for UIThread. It all happens on one fragment. Any good way to solve this ?

Here is the thread:

```
public void run() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bnavigation = (BottomNavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bnavigation);
                bnavigationImageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bnavigationImageView);
                maxPriceIMG = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.olx_price_max_img);
                minPriceIMG = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.olx_price_min_img);
                bnavigation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                bnavigationImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });


        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int tempCnt = 0;
                minPriceIMG.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if(maxPriceChecked) {
                    System.out.println("MAX CHECKED");
                    tempCnt++;
                }
                if(minPriceChecked) {
                    System.out.println("MIN CHECKED");
                    tempCnt++;
                }
                System.out.println("CNT: " + tempCnt);
                if(tempCnt==1) {
                    if(maxPriceChecked) {
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) maxPriceIMG.getLayoutParams();
                        params.horizontalBias = 0.5f;
                        maxPriceIMG.setLayoutParams(params);
                        maxPriceIMG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                    else {
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) minPriceIMG.getLayoutParams();
                        params.horizontalBias = 0.5f;
                        minPriceIMG.setLayoutParams(params);
                        minPriceIMG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                if(tempCnt==2) {
                    maxPriceIMG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    minPriceIMG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        olxSearch(); //<- heavy function, does a lot of web scraping
    }
```

Comment: This is not reproducible; likely you are doing something strange. There's no code, no stack-trace provided.

Comment: Going to update it in a moment!

Comment: Why is the app doing webscraping? Might be better to call to an api and return a result?

Comment: When it crashes what is the stack-trace?

Comment: When it crashes it prints out that:
getActivity().runOnUiThread(....)

Is null object reference